# Picking a folder using Application.FileDialog

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Application.FileDialog to let the user select a folder, as in:

```
Dim F As FileDialog
Set F = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

In this case the default folder contains no subfolders, so what the user sees is an empty box. Ideally, the dialog would not just list folders, but would list files disabled/grayed out so that the user would be able to see the contents of the folder he is picking.

Is there a way to do this on the cheap with a FileDialog or do I have to create my own form (ugh) ?

Comment: In my opinion, what you are already doing is the best approach. An (over complex) alternative would be to use the SHBrowseForFolder API function which is what I use to use a long time ago: http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/SHBrowseForFolder.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something from my database. I have been using this for quite sometime now for **VBA**. This code is **not** mine and I found it long time ago on the web.

```
Sub Sample()
    ret = BrowseForFolder("C:\")
End Sub

Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ShellApp As Object

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Else
        GoTo Invalid
    End Select

    Exit Function

Invalid:
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```

Comment: This is another way of picking a folder, but when I tested it out it still didn't solve my problem - i.e. allowing the user to see what's inside the folder before picking.  Is there a tweak that accomplishes this ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The other alternative is as you suggested, Create your own form.

Comment: I found a way to do it (sort of) at the following link:  http://www.your-save-time-and-improve-quality-technologies-online-resource.com/vba-select-folder.html.   Displays folders + contents  (lets you pick either, so not perfect, but best I could find).  Anyway I'm accepting your answer anyway, not perfect but A for effort.