# Defaulting a folder for FileDialog in VBA

Tags: vba, filedialog

```
Private Sub Command93_Click()

    Dim f As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim P As String
    Dim DeleteEverything As String

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DeleteEverything = "DELETE * FROM [TABLE]"
        DoCmd.RunSQL DeleteEverything

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If f.Show Then
        For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
            strFile = Dir(varItem)
            strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
            P = strFolder & strFile
        Next
    End If
    Set f = Nothing

        DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "[IMPORT SPECIFICATION]", "[TABLE]", P, False

End Sub
```

How to make the FileDialog default to a specific folder when it initially opens?

Comment: Check out the code provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399651/picking-a-folder-using-application-filedialog

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Add the folder path (including the trailing `\`) to `InitialFileName`. For example, to open the dialog in the user's home directory do:

```
f.InitialFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\"
```

If you forget the trailing `\`, 
then the dialog box will still open in the correct folder, 
but the folder name will also appear as the default selected file name. 
Then the dialog will be looking for a sub-folder with the same name, which usually doesn't exist.

Comment: I think `Application.PathSeparator` instead of `"\"` will be better

Comment: @johnc.j. Why would you say that? "\" is the path seperator

Comment: @Davesexcel It seems you use Windows. On macOS and Linux it will be "/". `Application.PathSeparator` will work anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I tried ChDir "your\path\here" and it works

Comment: please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Or, before opening the dialog, simply change the deault file directory with:

```
Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath) = "your\path\here"
```

Comment: This code is only good for use with MS Word, the OP is asking about MS Access