# MS Access msoFileDialogFilePicker, hard codeFolder Location

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code which allows user to select file.  That portion works; but I would like the initial location of the folder that the user will be browsing to to be hard coded.

```
Private Sub InputFile_Click()
Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim filename As Variant
Dim varFile As Variant
Dim oApp As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' Clear listbox contents. '
 Me.TextBoxName = ""

 ' Set up the File Dialog. '
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fDialog

  .AllowMultiSelect = False

  ' Set the title of the dialog box. '
  .Title = "Please choose File"

  ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.'
   .Filters.Clear
   .Filters.Parent = "R:\Location of where file typically resides\"
   .Filters.Add "Excel csv", "*.csv"
  .Filters.Add "Flat File txt", "*.txt"
  .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

  ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the '
  ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns '
  ' False, the user clicked Cancel. '
  If .Show = True Then

     'Loop through each file selected and add it to our list box. '
     For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
             filename = Right(varFile, 51)
       FileCopy varFile, "\\network\location\" & filename
                  Me.TextBoxName = filename
   Next
  Else
     MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
  End If
  End With
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I ended up finding the solution on StackOverflow
[Defaulting a folder for FileDialog in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917122/defaulting-a-folder-for-filedialog-in-vba)

```
 f.InitialFileName = "[DESIRED PATH]"
```

Now I am wondering if there is a way for initial view to be soreted by most recent on top.

```
 InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
```