# Mistake with FileDialog in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, filedialog

In access I have implemented a routine that allows the user to choose an image file in a subfolder of the application folder. The routine was achieved as follows:

```
Public Function FotoOpen(DirStart As String, SubDir As String) As String
    ' Questa procedura apre il file dialog per la selezione della foto

    Dim PathDir As String
    PathDir = DirStart

   If SubDir <> "" Then
      PathDir = PathDir & "\" & SubDir & "\"
   End If

   '  Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
   Dim Fp As Office.FileDialog
   Set Fp = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With Fp
      .Title = "Selezionare file immagine"
      .ButtonName = "Conferma"
      .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewPreview
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Tutti i Files (*.*)", "*.*"
      .Filters.Add "Images Files (*.jpg)", "*.jpg" '
      .Filters.Add "Images Files (*.bmp)", "*.BMP"
      .Filters.Add "Images Files (*.png)", "*.png"
      .Filters.Add "Images Files (*.ico)", "*.ico"
      .FilterIndex = 2
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewPreview
      .InitialFileName = PathDir

      If .Show = -1 Then
        FotoOpen = CStr(.SelectedItems.Item(1))
      Else
         Beep
       '  MsgBox "La selezione è stata annullata", vbInformation, "Informazione"
      End If

    End With
  Set Fp = Nothing
 End Function
```

But The Dialog doesn't seem to take into account the initial Dir passed, but it always opens on the Documents folder.
Where's the mistake?
Thank you all.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you 100% sure you are passing correct path names to the function? Add `Debug.Print PathDir` and `Debug.Print Dir(PathDir)` after building `PathDir`. Perhaps you have double \\ in there.

Comment: Also make sure `PathDir` always ends with a '\' (or `Application.PathSeparator`), see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917122/defaulting-a-folder-for-filedialog-in-vba

Comment: @Andre Facendo il `Debug.Print PathDir` ottengo `H:\Sviluppo\SVILUPPO_VBA\TEMP4YOU\bmp\`  che è corretto ma facendo il `Debug.Print .InitialFileName` ottengo   `C:\Users\Antonio Lipone\OneDrive\Documenti\`  che non è corretto. Sembra che l'istruzione: `.InitialFileName=PathDir` non va a buon fine. `InitialFileName`  mantiene il suo valore originale, sebbene la documentazione dica altro.
mi sembra un pò un mistero! Che ne pensi?

Comment: I don't speak Italian... but it seems you are missing the `\\` at the end of PathDir.

Comment: @Andre Solved. The problem was due because the SubDir had been changed from bmp to img so it was not found
Thank you for everything