# OLEObject export to file path - MSACESS

Tags: vba, ms-access, ole

I have a button in MS access to export an OLE word document.

```
 Private Sub Command25_Click()
    Set OLEobj = Me.POLICY_OLE
    OLEobj.SaveAs Me.TRANSACTION_TYPE.Value & Me.TRANSACTION_NUMBER.Value & ".doc"
    Set OLEobj = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is working fine but I would like to define the file path say

```
C:\Me.TRANSACTION_TYPE.Value & Me.TRANSACTION_NUMBER.Value & ".doc"
```

Comment: So concatenate drive reference literal text with variables, just as you are with ".doc": `"C:\" & `. But tries to save a root. So expand that with whatever path you want. If you want to allow user to select folder, then use FileDialog. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917122/defaulting-a-folder-for-filedialog-in-vba

Comment: Thanks it worked i must have missed adding the '&'