# How to add Directory Chooser to macro

Tags: excel, directory, vba

Instead of hard coding the directory I would like to open up a directory chooser function so that user can pick Source folder and Target folder for the following:

```
Sub XlsToTxt()
    Dim aFile As String
    Const SourceFolder = "C:\Users\Documents\PCS\" ' note the backslash at the end of the string
    Const targetFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\PCS Text\" ' note the backslash at the end of the string
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    aFile = Dir(SourceFolder & "*.xls")
    Do While aFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open SourceFolder & aFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs targetFolder & Left(aFile, Len(aFile) - 4) _
        & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV _
        , CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        aFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399651/picking-a-folder-using-application-filedialog) post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub XlsToTxt()
    Dim aFile As String
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim targetFolder As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Select Source folder"
      .Show
      On Error Resume Next
      SourceFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Select Target folder"
      .Show
      On Error Resume Next
      targetFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If SourceFolder = "" Or targetFolder = "" Then Exit Sub

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    aFile = Dir(SourceFolder & "*.xls")
    Do While aFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open SourceFolder & aFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs targetFolder & Left(aFile, Len(aFile) - 4) _
        & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV _
        , CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        aFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this: `fnameandpath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File")`

will open a file picker dialog for a user to choose a source and target file. They may browse normally and when selecting a file the fullpath and filename is returned for processing

### edit

to add filter - `fnameandpath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls",Title:="Select File")`